# Html.ActionLink cannot be dynamically dispatched

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have a problem with MVC3

I'm trying to use `@Html.ActionLink()` to generate a Link for titles in my blog project.

Using constant strings in `ActionLink` works just dandy, but if I use `Posts.Title` (the Title of the current Post model being looped), I get this exception:

```
CS1973: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' has no applicable method 
named 'ActionLink' but appears to have an extension method by that name.  
Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting  
the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the  
extension method syntax.
```

Answer (score 108, accepted):

"Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax."

Posts.Title doesn't have a type (hence dynamic argument).

Just cast it via (string)Posts.Title.

Comment: That fixed it, thanks a lot. I'm no good at decrypting error messages.

Comment: Casting the dynamic arguments WORKS like a charm!

Comment: Also worked for <%= Html.TextBox("Name", (object)Model) %>: I needed the (object) cast to avoid the error.

Comment: Since this answer is still found and appreciated by newcomers, I should probably add that making the view strongly typed by specifying the type of your Model will also solve this problem, and in a more elegant fashion than casting your arguments.

Comment: @AndreasCarlbom, Can you perhaps give an example of how to make the view strongly typed? I am using `@model MyViewModel` and getting an `IShapeProxy` error.

Comment: Example of strongly typed views: http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/10/13/asp-net-mvc-3-beta-strongly-typed-views-in-razor.aspx

Comment: @AndreasCarlbom, I got this message when reading an informational message from the view bag in a strongly typed view. In that case, the solution with casting to string is still useful. Although one could reasonably argue that using the view bag should be avoided as well. Anyway, you got my upvote :-)

Comment: @Html.ActionLink((string)@item.concern_desc, "Details", new { id = @item.concern_id }, null)