# Helpers and action links in ASP.net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, actionlink

So I am having a weird issue with a helper I created:

```
@if (Model != null)
{
    <ul>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <li>
           @Html.ActionLink(item.name, "Map", "Home", new { id = item.id }, null)
        </li>
    }
    </ul>
}
else
{
    <p><strong>ATTN!!</strong> We could not find any locations.</p>
}
```

When when rendered into the view, throws the following error upon running:

> CS1973: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' has no applicable method named 'ActionLink' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.

This happens on my action link.

I have seen other partials use action links, some with [] around the action links other with out. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: cast the `item.name` to string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Html.ActionLink cannot be dynamically dispatched](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832692/html-actionlink-cannot-be-dynamically-dispatched)

Comment: casting string worked.

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast `item.name` to a string, by the way if you don't use the `htmlAttributes` parameter, leave it instead of putting `null` for cleaner code

Comment: you must use `null` for `htmlAttributes` when using `routeVaules` otherwise the the third parameter will be consider the `htmlAttributes`

Comment: Oh yes ofc, was confused with the item.name, thought first there were only 2 params before the routevalue, my bad