# add viewmodel to html.partial can't resolve

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

```
@model Pam.Presentation.Models.ViewModel.EditProductViewModel
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "EditProduct";
   Layout = null;
}

<div id="product-tabstrip" class="row">
<ul>
    <li id="productinformation-tab">Product Information</li>
    <li>Product Categories</li>
</ul>
<div id="productinformation">
    @{ Html.Partial("_ProductInformation", model); }
</div>
<div id="productcategories">
    @{ Html.Partial("_ProductCategories", model); }
</div>
```

this is my partial:

```
@model Pam.Presentation.Models.ViewModel.EditProductViewModel
<h4>ProductInformation</h4>
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
      <label for=""></label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Is this not the way to do it? Why can't i add model to my partial?

```
   @{ Html.Partial("_ProductInformation", model); }
```

it can't revolve model in the row above. Why not?

Comment: because it's not 'model' but 'Model'

Answer (score 2):

```
use Model instead of model:

    @{ Html.Partial("_ProductInformation", Model); }
```

Comment: I get the error: extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched

Comment: Do you have @model Pam.Presentation.Models.ViewModel.EditProductViewModel in your partialview?

Comment: yes, i just pass it on from my view to my partialviews

Comment: then this error may be due to some dynamic argument in your data not sure http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832692/html-actionlink-cannot-be-dynamically-dispatched

Comment: i tired to cast it (EditProductViewModel)Model but that didn't work either